# How to move autosys job out of the box?

Tags: autosys

I have a job which runs in the box.

```
insert_job: template job_type: c
box_name: box1
.
.
.
```

I want to move this job out of the `box1` What change should I make in the JIL definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update an existing job use **update_job**.

```
update_job: template job_type: c
box_name:
```

Keep the **box_name** attribute as blank and run the JIL.

This removes the job from the defined box.